# Visual Studio 2012 not loading report server project

Tags: visual-studio

I have a VS2010 solution with around ten projects inside (web, class library, report server project) which persist on source control.

Before few days I installed VS2012 and try to load all that projects from source control.

Every project was loaded and successfully build, just one was not, and that one is report server project.

In solution explorer I have description for that project that isn't compatible.

What can be problem?

Comment: Can you post more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go grab the BI Tools for VS2012 (released March 5, 2013) and what you're trying will work:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843